# How should I serialize an object containing a large list of objects?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, clr

I'm using c# and .net 4.5.

I have an class SomeData that contains a member _SomeEvents, which is a Dictionary. The SomeData class also contains a bunch of information e.g. the time the data was generated, the user that generated it etc.

I'm trying to save a SomeData object to file using formatter.Serialize but hitting an OutOfMemoryException when the object is large (e.g. 1GB)

```
IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
Stream stream;
stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
formatter.Serialize(stream, _myObject);
stream.Close();
```

Other posts I've read suggest that the out-of-memory issue is caused by an inability to find a large enough contiguous area of free memory to generate the data to be written to disk. I also read that this is the 'wrong' way of serializing - my assumption is that if I were doing it correctly the CLR would write data as it goes rather than attempt to prepare it all in memory before saving it. That said - I do see a large file get created before the serialize operation fails, implying that it is writing as it goes.

I've tried changing the Serialize operation to write the Dictionary object itself rather than the object that contains the Dictionary - same problem, I get the memory exception.

**Questions:**

1. Why would Serialize run into this memory problem - even when I give it a Dictionary object to serialize - as surely it write as it goes?
2. Is there a better way of doing this?!!

Here's the full exception:

> Unable to save file: System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
>
> at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectIDGenerator.Rehash()
>
> at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectIDGenerator.GetId(Object obj, Boolean& firstTime)
>
> at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.InternalGetId(Object obj, Boolean assignUniqueIdToValueType, Type type, Boolean& isNew)
>
> at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.WriteString(NameInfo memberNameInfo, NameInfo typeNameInfo, Object stringObject)
>
> at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.WriteKnownValueClass(NameInfo memberNameInfo, NameInfo typeNameInfo, Object data)
>
> at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.WriteMembers(NameInfo memberNameInfo, NameInfo memberTypeNameInfo, Object memberData, WriteObjectInfo objectInfo, NameInfo typeNameInfo, WriteObjectInfo memberObjectInfo)
>
> at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.WriteMemberSetup(WriteObjectInfo objectInfo, NameInfo memberNameInfo, NameInfo typeNameInfo, String memberName, Type memberType, Object memberData, WriteObjectInfo memberObjectInfo)
>
> at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.Write(WriteObjectInfo objectInfo, NameInfo memberNameInfo, NameInfo typeNameInfo, String[] memberNames, Type[] memberTypes, Object[] memberData, WriteObjectInfo[] memberObjectInfos)
>
> at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.Write(WriteObjectInfo objectInfo, NameInfo memberNameInfo, NameInfo typeNameInfo)
>
> at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.Serialize(Object graph, Header[] inHeaders, __BinaryWriter serWriter, Boolean fCheck)
>
> at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Serialize(Stream serializationStream, Object graph, Header[] headers, Boolean fCheck)
>
> at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Serialize(Stream serializationStream, Object graph)

Comment: See following posting : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/vstudio/en-US/4aa0ebcc-1585-403f-a249-9ae435812f21/max-size-xml-serialize-can-handle

Comment: Thanks, though it looks like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25148793/whats-a-good-memory-conservative-serializer-to-replace-binaryformatter is in the right area. I'm going to try handling the serialize operation of each of my events 1 (or x) at a time to see if I can avoid this problem with BinaryFormatter graph serializer

Comment: I've just switched to protobuf-net and my memory woes have disappeared! Admittedly I end up with a 400MB file for 1m events but I can write that to a temp file then gzip it to 8MB after doing the initial deserialize.

Comment: See this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3863793/c-sharp-serialize-large-array-to-disk

Answer (score 0):

Serialize each object using a stream.  See an example :
NOTE : This is just a template not a complete code.  I just want to give you an idea.

```
private void SerializeObjects(List<foo> foos, Stream stream)
{
    foreach (var f in foos)
    {
        stream.Write(f);
    }
}

private void DeserializeObjects(List<foo> foos, Stream stream)
{
    foo f = stream.ReadFoo();
    while (f != null)
    {
        foos.Add(f);
        f = stream.ReadFoo();
    }
}
```

Comment: I got SerializeObjects working okay, but what is stream.ReadFoo();
 ? A method I have to write myself?

Comment: ReadFoo is just an example since you can read from many ways.  Just use the Read that you need from the stream.  See the stream class.  I would say a MemoryStream is what you have to serialize and deserialize